# How to prevent installation to run from UI?

Tags: drush, 8, installation, installation-profiles

I have an installation profile that will be installed purely via Drush/CLI. So I need to prevent anyone to run the installation from web interface.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify hidden: true in the info yml file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to prevent my profile to be installed. I meant to prevent running the installation process from the UI as whole. Like deleting the install file but not that intrusive.

Comment: @IvanJaros No answer yet? Got the same problem...

Comment: @TNT I have ended up with different setup now. I have CI that runs the whole installation process and creates sql dump and I have removed the installation file and now I create new "instances" just by importing the sql dump + custom setup wizard form.